# Non-exhaustive patterns in function toEnum

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, typeclass, ghci

For some reason, my ghci keeps giving this warning "Non-exhaustive patterns in function toEnum", here's my code:

```
data Rank = Numeric Int | Jack | Queen | King | Ace deriving (Eq,Ord)

instance Show Rank where
        show (Numeric n) = show n
        show Jack = "J"
        show Queen = "Q"
        show King = "K"
        show Ace = "A"

data Suit = Spades | Hearts | Diamonds | Clubs deriving (Eq,Ord,Bounded)

instance Show Suit where
        show Spades = "♠"
        show Hearts = "♥"
        show Diamonds = "♦"
        show Clubs = "♣"

data Card = Card {rank::Rank, suit::Suit} deriving (Eq, Ord)

instance Show Card where
        show (Card r s) = show r++show s

instance Enum Rank where
        succ (Numeric 10) = Jack
        succ (Numeric a) = Numeric (succ a)
        succ Jack = Queen
        succ Queen = King
        succ King = Ace
        succ Ace = Ace
        pred Ace = King
        pred King = Queen
        pred Queen = Jack
        pred Jack = (Numeric 10)
        pred (Numeric 2) = Numeric 2
        pred (Numeric a) = Numeric (pred a)
        fromEnum (Numeric a) = a
        fromEnum Jack = 11
        fromEnum Queen = 12
        fromEnum King = 13
        fromEnum Ace = 14
        toEnum 14 = Ace
        toEnum 13 = King
        toEnum 12 = Queen
        toEnum 11 = Jack
        toEnum a = (Numeric a)

instance Enum Suit where
        succ Spades = Hearts 
        succ Hearts = Diamonds
        succ Diamonds = Clubs
        succ Clubs = Spades
        pred Clubs = Diamonds
        pred Diamonds = Hearts
        pred Hearts = Spades
        pred Spades = Clubs
        fromEnum Spades = 1
        fromEnum Hearts = 2
        fromEnum Diamonds = 3
        fromEnum Clubs = 4
        (toEnum) 4 = Clubs
        (toEnum) 3 = Diamonds
        (toEnum) 2 = Hearts
        (toEnum) 1 = Spades

instance Enum Card where
        succ (Card (a) (Clubs)) = Card (succ a) (succ Clubs) 
        succ (Card (a) (b)) = Card (a) (succ b)
        fromEnum (Card (a) (b)) = (fromEnum(a) * 4) + (fromEnum b)
        toEnum a = Card (toEnum(a`div`4)) (toEnum(a`mod`4))
```

So, he says it is in the line 60 until the line 63, when I'm using toEnum in the Suits data. So, I always have this error when I try to "toEnum" a card that belongs to the Spades class, the another classes I have no problem, can anyone help me?

Comment: If it calls `toEnum 0`, or `toEnum 5`, then it will indeed raise a non-exaustive error.

Answer (score 3):

> For some reason, my ghci keeps giving this warning "Non-exhaustive patterns in function toEnum".

That makes perfect sense since for all values except `4`, `3`, `2` and `1`, there is no clause that will fire. One can pass any `Int` value to the `toEnum` function, hence for example for `toEnum 0`, it will error.

You can for example specify to raise an error with:

```
import GHC.Enum(toEnumError)

instance Enum Suit where
        succ Spades = Hearts 
        succ Hearts = Diamonds
        succ Diamonds = Clubs
        succ Clubs = Spades
        pred Clubs = Diamonds
        pred Diamonds = Hearts
        pred Hearts = Spades
        pred Spades = Clubs
        fromEnum Spades = 1
        fromEnum Hearts = 2
        fromEnum Diamonds = 3
        fromEnum Clubs = 4
        toEnum 4 = Clubs
        toEnum 3 = Diamonds
        toEnum 2 = Hearts
        toEnum 1 = Spades
        toEnum n = toEnumError "Suit" n (minBound :: Suit, maxBound)
```

Furthermore you better use values between `0` and `3`, especially since later you use `` n `div` 4 ``, which is a value between `0` and `3`. So:

```
import GHC.Enum(toEnumError)

instance Enum Suit where
        succ Spades = Hearts 
        succ Hearts = Diamonds
        succ Diamonds = Clubs
        succ Clubs = Spades
        pred Clubs = Diamonds
        pred Diamonds = Hearts
        pred Hearts = Spades
        pred Spades = Clubs
        fromEnum Spades = 0
        fromEnum Hearts = 1
        fromEnum Diamonds = 2
        fromEnum Clubs = 3
        toEnum 0 = Spades
        toEnum 1 = Hearts
        toEnum 2 = Diamonds
        toEnum 3 = Clubs
        toEnum n = toEnumError "Suit" n (minBound :: Suit, maxBound)
```

Comment: now, it gives: 7*** Exception: Enum.toEnum{Suit}: tag (0) is outside of bounds (♠,♣)

Comment: @DavíSilva: of course, the point is that you specify that it should raise an exception, but at compile time you say that all the elements are covered. For values less than `1` or greater than `4`, there is no result, but you should add a clause to specify what to do, whereas if you leave it blank, the compiler raises a warning, because it assumes you forgot this.

Comment: I see, so my "toEnum" is wrong? because, for example, I put on terminal:  "fromEnum (Card (Numeric 1) Clubs)", it returns 8, but if I put "toEnum 8::Card", it returns 2*** Exception: Enum.toEnum{Suit}: tag (0) is outside of bounds (♠,♣)

Comment: @DavíSilva: not per se "wrong", but a NonExhaustive error in a program looks *ugly* and does not explain what happens.

Comment: Idk what to do :( , I can't see why Spades is outside of bounds

Comment: @DavíSilva: exactly *what* function do you call?

Comment: *Main> toEnum 12::Card
3*** Exception: Enum.toEnum{Suit}: tag (0) is outside of bounds (♠,♣)

*Main> toEnum 8::Card
2*** Exception: Enum.toEnum{Suit}: tag (0) is outside of bounds (♠,♣)

Comment: @DavíSilva: If you calculate `div n 4`, this is a value between `0` and `3`, so if you use `1..4` as values, that will not work.